# Killing Process System.exit(1);

Tags: android, exit, kill-process, android-version

I need help.

First I use:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
```

this code is run fine but I change my device and version of androids are different, first I use android 4.0 ,now I change to android 4.2 and It not work, when I test application, it not exit but it refresh that page. I want to know about is it concerned with version of android or not?, Are there other codes can replace this code?

Thank you very much

Comment: Simply delete the code. There is no need for you to kill your own process, and doing so can harm the user experience.

Comment: My application is need to close because I use the google voice recognition and if I didn't close it, it still running.

Comment: Call `cancel()` and `destroy()` on your `SpeechRecognizer`. Otherwise, you are welcome to provide evidence that developers using "google voice recognition" needs to terminate their process, such as documentation to that effect, a bug report indicating that this is required, etc.

Comment: I mean, I use this code for voice command. If you say Exit, this application will detect your sound and it will exit the application.

Comment: Then have "Exit" call `startActivity()` to bring up the device's home screen. There is no need for you to kill your own process, and doing so can harm the user experience.